# How can I fix it "comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]"

Tags: c++

I tried to add unsigned, but the error still occurred, cpplint swears a lot because of this, I'm just tired and want to sleep(

```
string MinHeap::get_binary_string(unsigned int n,
    unsigned int bit_size = -1) {
    stringstream stream;
    string reverse_binary, binary_str;
    do {
        stream << n % 2;
        n /= 2;
    } while (n);
    unsigned int sizeB = bit_size;
    if (sizeB != -1 && stream.str().size() < sizeB) {
        unsigned int padding_size = sizeB - stream.str().size();
        while (padding_size--) {
            stream << '0';
        }
    }
```

Comment: if (sizeB != -1 && stream.str().size() < sizeB)
Throws an error on this line

Comment: In your code, `-1` is negative, and you are comparing it against an `unsigned`.

Comment: Use `~0` to get the unsigned equivalent of `-1`

Comment: it didn't help unfortunately

Comment: What does "it didn't help" mean? Please show actual code, show what you've tried, instead of describing it. Please show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste into an empty file, then try to compile and reproduce your compilation error, exactly.

Comment: `const unsigned int sizeNotSet = -1;` and then `sizeB != sizeNotSet` as the condition is one way to avoid the error and get the expected result while improving readability of your code by using a constant that explain the special value. The other way is to avoid mixing signed and unsigned intergers in a given expression.

Comment: @Razumoska because `~0` is still an `int`. Use `~0u` to get `unsigned int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the expression `sizeB != -1`.

The variable `sizeB` is an unsigned int, and the expression `-1` results in a signed int.  Since comparing signed values to unsigned values is very often a programming error, many compilers will warn you when it happens.

In your case, the `-1` is just a special value carved out of the otherwise expected range of sizes.  So it's not actually a bug.

There are many ways to change the code to do the same thing while assuring the compiler that you know what you're doing.

1. Don't use unsigned types.  There are many folks on the C++ standards committee who believe that making sizes unsigned was once a necessary evil but is now a bad programming practice.  (I don't find their arguments entirely persuasive, and it's often impractical to switch to signed values without breaking existing code and library interfaces.)
2. Make the implicit type conversions explicit.  One way to do this would be to rewrite the expression as `sizeB != static_cast<unsigned>(-1)`.  As @Phil1970 suggested, you can define a constant with your magic value as the right type, though I would probably write it as `constexpr auto sizeNotSet = static_cast<unsigned>(-1);`.
3. Express your magic value as an unsigned value.  `sizeB != std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` or `sizeB != (0u - 1)`.

Comment: I disagree with "Don't use unsigned types." as a general guideline.   Use the sign-ness approximate for the job.  With `get_binary_string()`, an unsigned type is a good choice for the task.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I disagree as well, but I included it because you're likely to hear it somewhere.   It's a common style guideline (e.g., Google's style guide still recommends it, although the advice has de-emphasized) and a lot of C++ bigwigs (including Bjarne Stroustrup) recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand why your unsigned ints shouldn't be defined to -1? That would lead you into undefined code. Either declare them signed or pick a different default value.

Comment: It's perfectly well defined to assign -1 to an unsigned int.  It is, however, often indicative of an mistake, so many compilers will flag it as a warning.  But that's not what's happening here.  It's the comparison of an unsigned to a signed value, specifically `sizeB != -1`.  That's also perfectly legal and well defined, but it's very likely to be a programmer error, so even more compilers will flag that.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeB != -1` --> `sizeB != -1u`.

Consider the same with other constants `2` --> `2u`, etc.  Make them *unsigned*.  No cast needed.

Avoid mixing sign-ness in integer math.